Joint distribution uniquely determined by marginal distributions and property $\min(p_{a,b},p_{c,d})=0$ $\forall c<a$ and $b<d$
I am currently studying the proof of Theorem 3.14 in Chapter 3.5 in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-73480-0#toc.I and am struggling with the following problem: Assume $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables and let $p_{a,b}:=P(X=x_a,Y=x_b)$ with $1 \leq a,b \leq n$ with the property $\min(p_{a,b},p_{c,d})=0$ $\forall c<a$ and $b<d$. I would like to show that the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniquely determined by this property and by the marginal distributions. To do this, I considered the matrix $P_n:=(p_{a,b})_{1 \leq a,b \leq n}$ to show the claim by induction on $n$. The base case with $n=1$ or $n=2$ is clear to me. However, I have problems with the induction step, more precisely, I don't understand how to use the induction hypothesis. Perhaps you can explain this step to me using the example of the induction step from $n=1$ to $n=2$. I would be very grateful for your help.

Your problem is the following: you consider all probabilities $p_{ij}$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}^2=E\times F$  with given marginals $(r,s).$ Call this convex set $M(r,s)$. Furthermore you wonder if $p$ in $M(r,s)$ fullfils a certain condition $C$ about its support $S(p)=\{(i,j); p_{ij}>0\}$ then is it true that $p$ is unique? I mean: if $q\in M(r,s)$ is such that $S(p)=S(q)$ then do we have $p=q?$ (by the way this is equivalent to say that $p$ is an extreme point of the convex set $M(r,s)$). Well, call $S$ the set of $p$  such that $p$ fullfils $C$ and $S(p)=S.$
The trick is to consider the undirected graph $G$ on $E\cup F$ defined by $i\sim j$ if $(i,j) \in S.$ We have now the proposition
Let $p,q$ in $M(r,s)$ such that $S(p)=S(q)=S.$ Then $p=q$ if and only if $G$ has no cycle.
Proof $\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $S$ has a cycle $i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2,\ldots,i_k,j_k$ and define $q_{i,j}=p_{ij}+\epsilon$ if $i,j=i_r,j_r$ and $q_{i,j}=p_{ij}-\epsilon$ if $i,j=i_{r-1},j_r$ (with the convention $i_{-1}=i_k$) and take $q_{ij}=p_{ij}$ in other cases. We take $\epsilon $ small enough to have $q$ positive. Then $q\in M(r,s)$ and $S(q)=S:$ contradiction.
$\Leftarrow$ Suppose that there $p\neq q$ both in $M(r,s)$ and such that $S(p)=S(q)=S$ Then the margins of $p-q$ are zero. Consider the set $S_0=\{(i,j); p_{ij}-q_{ij}\neq 0\}.$ It is easy to see that the graph associated to $S_0$ contains a cycle (if not, it is a tree or a forest and cannot support a measure with zero margins.)
This theorem is due to Ethan Bolker (1972). Ethan appears sometimes on that site.
'Transformation polytopes' J. of Comb. Th 1972 vol 13 series B.
I have published  a somewhat more general result in Illinois Math Journal in 1966, but it is in French and you can be less interested.
Now your problem is not solved, since  you have  to analyse your complicated condition $C$ which is $\min\{p_{cd},p_{ab}\}=0$  for $c<a,b<d$ to decide if it satisfies the no cycle condition. This is now only a graph problem. But I am pessimistic since it seems you can find cycles entirely contained in $\{(i,j); i>j\}$
